# Shrinking Topologist's Sine Curve

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

The Topologist's Sine Curve is well-known:

> The set $S = \{(0,0)\} \cup \{(x, \sin(1/x))\ |\ x \in \left]0,1\right]\}$, as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is connected but not path-connected.

An intuitive reason is that no path from $S - \{(0,0)\}$ can reach $(0,0)$ in a finite amount of time. However, what if I shrink the distances involved? That is, consider
$$
S' = \{(0,0)\} \cup \{(x, x\sin(1/x))\ |\ x \in \left]0,1\right]\}.
$$

Is $S'$ path-connected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}x\sin\frac1x,&\text{if }0<x\le 1\\\\0,&\text{if }x=0\;;\end{cases}$$

then $f$ itself is already a path connecting any two points of $S'$.

Comment: Indeed, as $\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin{(\frac{1}{x})} = 0 = f(0)$

Comment: @Rustyn: Exactly. (But I figured that that was pretty well known.)

Comment: +1 nice answer@ Brian sir

Answer (score 1):

I should point out some subtlety here. The problem is never about infinite length of these curves. Remember that we have space filling (continuous) curves into $R^2$. So, why is it possible to turn the shrinking sine cure into a path, but the same is not possible for the usual sine curve?

The real answer is the non-/existence of the limit at zero. In both cases we already have a curve defined from $(0,1]$ into your space. In one case we can assign a value at $0$, and extend the function's domain continuously to the closed $[0,1]$, while in the other we cannot, since there is no limit at zero.

When can we extend a continuous function from $(0,1]$ to all of $[0,1]$? Precisely, if and only if the (original) function is uniformly continuous.